# Is it possible to prove continuity without nets?

Tags: functional-analysis

In the proof of the following theorem:

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then $\varphi : X \to \Omega (C(X))$ given by $x \mapsto e_x$ where $e_x$ is evaluation at $x$ and $\Omega$ is the character space is a homemomorphism.

Nets are used as follows:

This map is continuous because if $x_\lambda$ is a net converging to $x$ then for all $f\in C(X)$: $f(x_\lambda)$ converges to $f(x)$ hence the  net $e_{x_n}$ converges in the weak star topology.

My question is:  Is it possible to show that $\varphi$ is continuous without using nets? I tried to show that $\varphi^{-1}$ is open but couldn't finish the proof.

Comment: Well you're endowing $\Omega(C(X))$ with the weak-star topology so open sets are a little hard to imagine here. I think the best way to do it is via nets for sure. Really, I think this is the whole point of nets: they allow you to speak of convergence without having the open sets directly at your disposal (which is often the case in functional analysis).

Comment: Can you prove that it is linear? The point is that one has to choose the best approach. For example given topology in terms of a norm everything works best in terms of nets as one does not have to switch between sets and points. Another example given topology in terms of neighborhoods of zero everything works best in terms of filters. Now linearity would hint to take the second approach as one has to check only continuity at zero.

Comment: Can you write down what the topologies are? That's a good place to start.